# Catkin seems to be unavailable for Ros2 Foxy

Tags: ros, ament, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All of the details are right there in the title. I can't seem to get packages without Catkin, ament is included with Foxy but doesn't seem to work with colcon. Another way around this would be how to use packages without Catkin or ament at all.

For note i'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with the latest version of Foxy installed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/372565/catkin-seems-to-be-unavailable-for-ros2-foxy/) by [maxunm](https://answers.ros.org/users/70708/maxunm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2021-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Catkin does not support nor is supported in/with/for ROS 2 (there is some nuance possible here, but it's mostly true).

ROS 2 uses [Colcon](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial) to build packages.

> I can't seem to get packages without Catkin

as far as I can tell there are no packages in ROS 2 which depend on Catkin in their build scripts (ie: `CMakeLists.txt`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2